# Правильно ли я сделал цепочку функций используя promise

Tags: javascript

Напишите две функции, которые используют Promise и свяжите их в цепочку Первая
функция, makeAllCaps(), принимает массив слов и преобразует их в слова из заглавных
букв, а затем вторая функция sortWords() сортирует слова в алфавитном порядке. Если
массив содержит что-то кроме строк, он должен выдать ошибку.
Я сделал так , но не могу понять некоторые вещи. Почему я вызываю `makeAllCaps()` первую для массива ( использую функцию сортировки `sortWords`) , который должен обработаться правильно, но в консоли я вижу что первой обработался массив `complicatedArray`  который вызывает ошибку в функции `makeAllCaps()`. Но ещё я подумал зачем нам во второй функции `sortWords`  создавать promise. Как я понимаю мы проверяем массив на вхождение только строковых элементов в `makeAllCaps()` , а в методе sort мы просто сортируем. Поэтому я написал функцию `sortWordsSecond`, которая просто сортирует и тогда прядок вызова правильный

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 <style>
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<script>
const arrayOfWords = ['слон', 'лестница', 'дерево']
const complicatedArray = ['Вася', 74, true]
const makeAllCaps = (array) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let testArray = array.filter( item => typeof item == `string`);
   if ( testArray.length == array.length){
    let resultArray = array.map( item => item.toUpperCase());
    resolve(resultArray);
   }
   else{
    reject(new Error(`В данном массиве не все элементы являются строками`));
   }
 });
};

const sortWords = (array) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     if (array){
        resolve(array);
     }
     else{
        reject(new Error(`Ошибка`));
     }
 });
};

const sortWordsSecond = (array) => {
    return array.sort();
};

makeAllCaps(arrayOfWords)
 .then(sortWordsSecond)
 .then((result) => console.log(result))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))

makeAllCaps(complicatedArray)
 .then(sortWordsSecond)
 .then((result) => console.log(result))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Цепочки промисов правильные, но вот код сильно неграмотный (кстати, он не решает поставленную задачу).

Comment: А зачем вам функция `sortWords`, вы же ее нигде не используете? Ну и по заданию, функция сортировки тоже должна возвращать промис.